# linear layout click has no effect

Tags: android

I have a `LinearLayout` and i want clicking effect on it when i click on it. Here is my `LinearLayout` in XML.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect">
```

In my `onCreateView()` of fragment, I have:

```
myLyout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.d("hi","Click1");
        myLyout.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ripple_effect));
    }
});
```

It does not work. I don't even see the log message. What is the problem here?

Comment: Can you post the whole layout?

Comment: I think you are missing this line ``LinearLayout myLyout = (LinearLayout)view. findViewById(R.id.my_layout); ``

Comment: What is the API you are testing on? And the minimum API target?

Comment: @Harisali I am using butterknife. so i declare it with Bind

Comment: Can you put your java code??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try in onViewCreated, once view is fully rendered in screen, after that you can bind events and data., it's Good practice

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout myLayt = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
        myLayt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("hi","Click1");

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: @MagdHo0506 if answer is really helped, you should accept the answer

Answer (score 2):

Find the solution :

IN Xml

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/my_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect">
```

In Activity

```
LinearLayout myLayt = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
myLayt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("hi","Click1");

            }
        });
```

Comment: Did not help :(

Answer (score 1):

```
view.findViewById(R.id.my_layout).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("hi","Click1");
                myLyout.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ripple_effect));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you've declared it with bind you need to call in your `OnCreateView`: `ButterKnife.bind(this, view)` if it's a Fragment or in your `OnCreate()` if it's an `Activity`: `ButterKnife.bind(this)`

But as you're using `ButterKnife` there is an easier bind available for click events.

```
@BindView(R.id.my_layout) LinearLayout myLyout; // You still need to bind this up here as you call it in your onClick method

...

@OnClick(R.id.my_layout)
public void onMyLayoutClicked()
{
    Log.d("hi","Click1");
    myLyout.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ripple_effect));
}
```

With this method you will still need to call `ButterKnife.bind(this)` or `ButterKnife.bind(this, view)` depending on whether it's a `Fragment` or `Activity`.

Comment: The order in which you call `ButterKnife.bind()` matters. As the others have said, you might want to paste your full `onCreateView()` code.

Answer (score 1):

For ButterKnife you can do it like this :

```
   @OnClick(R.id.some_layout)
public void someClick(View view) {
    // do something
}
```